# ARSession + SCNView performance issue

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit

I was trying to do some investigation with ARKit. In its ARKit demo, either using ARSCNView or ARSession + metal, the performance is fine (on iPhone 6s, CPU about 50%). But if I replace ARSCNView with SCNView + ARSession, the CPU turns to over 100% after several seconds, and receive "*[Technique] World tracking performance is being affected by resource constraints [1]*" in the console.

Anybody knows why the SCNView reduces the performance vs ARSession + metal? And how does ARSCNView optimize with this issue?

Note: My demo project is simple: create a SceneKit based Game project, add following codes in the viewDidLoad function,

```
let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
configuration.planeDetection = .horizontal
arsession = ARSession()
arsession.run(configuration, options: ARSession.RunOptions(rawValue: 0))
```

Comment: Are you rendering the live video behind the model or just the model?  I have a project I've been working on where I also did ARSession + SCNView, but CPU ended up nowhere near 100%.

Comment: @drewster I doesn't render anything at all. It seems that this issue only exists on iPhone 6S(+) and iPhone 7(+). Tested on an iPhone X, the issue disappeares and CPU keeps at 40+%.

Comment: maybe it's just CPU difference?  I know X is much faster than 6S.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you need/want to use SCNView rather than ARSCNView, or is this more of just wondering why the performance isn't the same?  There is a related topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45511838/technique-world-tracking-performance-is-being-affected-by-resource-constraints

Comment: @drewster I don't think they are the same issue as ARSCNView works well. I need to use SCNView as I want to modify the background video, and do some off-screen rendering with SCNRenderer.